# How often should I merge changes commited on master - to my other git branches?

Tags: git

If I have a `master` branch.

I then checkout a `work` branch and make awesome changes, and some commits.

Then I have to fix something so I go back to `master` and checkout a branch called `fix`, fix what I need to do, and merge it into `master`.

My question is, should I then merge `master` onto `work` and continue, or should I continue on `work` where I was and merge it when I'm done?

I find myself having to go back to all the branches I work on and updating (merging changes to) each branch.

I get the feeling it's best to merge asap, but then find myself having to continuously update all the branches I work on. Is this unnecessary?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Refer to the always awesome Git Branching Model by Nive:

[image]

You see, you should merge `fix` (not `master`) to the `work` (aka `develop`) branch.

How often should you merge to `master`? Every stable release, of course.

Any other doubts? Look at the picture. :P

Source: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: After a few years...not so awesome.  https://www.endoflineblog.com/gitflow-considered-harmful

Answer (score 3):

You actually don't want to do "back merges" which is what you are doing. You want to have integration or release candidate branches where you merge in whatever you want to see what works. Google "Branch per Feature" to see how to keep your work organized, synced and flexible.

Comment: Rebasing features/dev branches to be up to date with master is not a bad idea though.

Comment: it breaks merge combinations. A merge/reset work flow is much cleaner.

Comment: I'm not a fan of that style of work. Occasionally rebasing to Master helps keep your history nice and linear. I'm not a linear-history-stickler, but if it's a simple rebase, that's my preferred way to work.

Comment: depends on how many people you're working with in parallel. Also depends on the type of application and the type of rollouts and rollbacks work best for you. Even though you don't like that style of work, it's the one style that will save you from a lot of potential headaches. Heavy tools like XCode and Visual Studio suck for development so most people feel they have no choice but to use more trunk based dev. It doesn't scale.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by trunk-based dev. Our workflow is very similar to the flow you outlined, except we tend towards frequent rebases over frequent merges. 1) This keeps the the history linear. Not strictly necessary, but makes the history much easier to reason about. 2) The avoids a history littered with merge commits. 3) Most importantly, this makes merges from feature branches into master (or integration) trivial. If you've thoroughly tested your feature branch after rebasing onto master, you can be sure that the branch will still function after it's merged.

Comment: the other problem with rebasing is that you do a much larger amount of conflict resolution as each commit is applied as a patch. With merges, you get aggregation of those processes.

Comment: "you must disclose your affiliation in your answers" http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion

Answer (score 1):

When master has moved forward, we:

```
git fetch               # get the latest master
git checkout my_branch  # work in my_branch
git rebase master       # replay my work on top of newer master
```

to keep up to date with the changed master (e.g. when a `fix` was applied to it) and then when we went to merge the branch in

```
git checkout master     # Do the work in master
git merge my_branch     # Bring in my branch
```

We aim to merge the branch in pretty quickly to avoid having to update a lot for changes.

We only work on 2 or 3 branches a day and when the branches are shared among developers we also keep them up to date with:

```
get fetch                         # Gets the latest version of branches including my_branch
git checkout my_branch            # Do the work in the my_branch
git reset --hard origin/my_branch # Reset to the latest version fetch in.
```